# Nginx reverse proxy and subdomains

Tags: configuration, proxy, nginx

I have some problem with Nginx configuration.
I've already searched for an issue but the proposed solutions I saw didn't work for me.

I have some apps on a tomcat server and some apps on a jboss server.
I configured on another server Nginx as reverse proxy and it works properly.
Now, what I would do is to have access to the apps on tomcat and jboss using domain names.
Eg. I have apps on tomcat onto this address: tomcat.domain.com:8080/app1 ; tomcat.domain.com:8080/app2 and so on, even for jboss apps..
With reverse proxy I have this output: proxy.domain.com/app1 proxy.domain.com/app2 and so on, so I don't have to specify neither the port number not the belonging to a specified server.
But I would use subdomains in this way: app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com and so on.
So, my configuration of Nginx , the one that works and used just for reverse proxy is that (i will report the lines about tomcat only, for simplicity):

```
upstream tomcat_server {

    server tomcat.domain.com:8080;
}
server {
     listen 80;
     location /app1 {
                  proxy_pass http://tomcat_server;
                  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                }
    }
```

For subdomain configuration I modified the part about server definition like this:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name app1.domain.com;
     location / {
                  proxy_pass http://tomcat_server/app1;
                  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                }
    }
```

as suggested in some forums , but it doesn't work.
I specify that, on the server that manage DNS app1.domain.com points to the proxy.domain.com server.
I saw logs, but there wasn't any.
What should I do?

Thanks

Luciana

Answer (score 5):

You may want to check your DNS setup.

I also use multiple subdomains which I create on the fly for various applications using web frameworks such as Python Django or Ruby on Rails.

A typical example is at `mydomain.com` I may want to have `myapp.mydomain.com` where myapp is a framework served at `my_server_IP:some_port`.

In order to achieve such thing (many subdomains on the fly at the same OR different ports) I delegate the decision from the DNS to the Web server with a **Wildcard DNS record** [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record). As the name suggests, such record produces **a catch all** domain which can be easily managed from the web server with the use of virtual hosts - domain proxys, etc.

An `A` wildcard record at GoDaddy's DNS management tool looks like this:

`Host    Points To           TTL`

`*    YOUR_SERVER_IP        1 Hour`

And an Nginx configuration file which passes all requests for `app.mydomain.com` to `otherserver.com:9000/index.html`

**The result:** you type in browser `http://app.mydomain.com` and Nginx serves content from `otherserver.com:9000/index.html` which can be another server or application, etc

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name app.mydomain.com www.app.mydomain.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/app_mydomain_com_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/pp_mydomain_com_error.log;

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://otherserver.com:9000/index.html;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

DNS were all rights, I was doing some trial in local domain before putting them on production.. I solved the issue more easier (I don't have index.html or any other files, I have only folder name).. Finally, I think this would be helpful for someone, the configuration is:

```
upstream tomcat_server {
    server tomcat.domain.com:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://tomcat_server/app1/;
        sub_filter /app1/  /;
    }
}
```

***The " /" at the end of proxy_pass is necessary ...***

sub_filter is needed to avoid that the result would be something like

```
   app1.domain.com/app1
```

That's all.. I'm trying to improve this configuration for app working with tomcat 6, because the use of subdomains could generate (as in my case) some disease in the apps.