# How do I hide the IP & port in my URL in the browser?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2, dns

Some information:

If I go to mysite.com:9999 I get my site like 45.40.45.40:9999 .. and the 45.40.45.40 is the public ip of my router followed by the non-standard port used to connect my apache server on virtualbox on ubuntu.

I use dns redirect from namecheap.com in order to redirect mysite.com to my public_ip:used_port_to_connect_Apache so it wil be like so: 45.40.45.40:9999 in the url after I get connected.

My question is: how can I convert/returned the '45.40.45.40:9999' to the original domain name which is mysite.com only?

What do I need to do? Is this an Apache configuration setting somewhere? It is a Virtual Host on Apache server.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.conf:

```
Listen 9999

<VirtualHost *:9999>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin info@mysite.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Please help.

Comment: what is the redirect good for at all? Can't you make mysite.com resolve to the IP address directly?

Comment: If I made mysite.com resolve to the ip address only without the port next to it like: mysite.com it will open my router page only which is on my public ip .. but If i put the port beside it which is the port I forward it to the virtual server pc it will reach the server with no problem. and i am using non-standard port to reach my server because port 80 is blocked/reserved by my isp.

Comment: Is there a close tag `</VirtualHost>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make mysite.com resolve to 45.40.45.40. Then connect to http://mysite.com:9999 from your browser. There is no redirect needed. Also no need to change anything in your router or apache configuration.

If you want to hide the port number as well you have to replace the redirect you originally did with a reverse proxy. That would be some server (apache, nginx, ...) that listens on port 80 and **proxies** the request to the real web server. All requests will always go through this reverse proxy. There are already answers how to set up reverse proxies, e. g. this:

[Nginx reverse proxy and subdomains](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500638/nginx-reverse-proxy-and-subdomains)

However, the effort to do this is quite high and all you gain is that you have a few characters less in your URL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is no issue in connecting my website ,, I can reach the server easily .. the problem here is I want the url appeared in my browser like: mysite.com and not like http://45.40.45.40:9999 cause its looking bad and the port used is showing! I want the url returned to my domain name after the redirection done .. which is mysite.com on the browser.

Comment: Thank you "Sebastian Stark" to your simply answer .. well I found your answer is the best one between different website. Last solution I made as you recommended .. I used A Record in my dns setup .. and the host is @ .. and the value is my ip address .. without any port .. then I add my port to the browser in the url .. and it works! my ip as well is hidden in the browser after entered the website. I may satisfy with this point and will skip the nginx solution maybe for future. thanks again.